# How to rebase and choose which changes I want in Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Git newbie here, thanks in advance for the assistance and patience.

I have a branch with tag A, which I checked out, edited, and published as branch B.  I have since made multiple commits to branch B. I've also realized that I want to keep some of the changes I made in branch B, but not all of them.  since I've made a number of commits, I'm not sure  specifically which commits to revert. Given that, I'd like a way to start with the original tag A code and have VS Code show me the changes I've made in B so I can click on each section of code  and either keep or not keep what I need.

Is something like this possible? I have done rebasing before but am by no means an expert.

Comment: If you know which commits to select then you can use `git cherry-pick <<commitSha>>` command

Comment: In this case, I don't know exactly which commits to select. Also, I'll want some changes from a given commit but not others.

The experience I'm looking for is to:
1. Start with the original code from tag A
2. Have VS. Code interactively show me which changes have been made in branch B
3. Let me accept/reject each change and hand edit as needed

Is that possible?

Comment: What you are looking for is interactive rebase: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: also look at `git checkout -p`